# Logos on the rear

Tags: replace

How do I get my Subaru Outback tags on the back of my car off? They need to be replaced with the right colour. It has gold lettering and it’s suppose to have silver I’m told. I wouldn’t have thought it mattered but they are quite well stuck on though. Thanks in advance

Comment: [This Q&A should provide you the right information.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/53048/4152) Using fishing line is superior to heat, because there's no chance of causing damage to the paint due to the excessive heat which may occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "best" way is to use a heat gun - this should soften the adhesive...

Be VERY careful - with temperature : paint discoloration or badge discoloration / distortion is a possibility...